# JQuery if statements & attribute values

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a simple calculator for a project I'm working on. JQuery and JavaScript isn't really familiar to me. My code should allow the user to enter an amount, if the amount in the input box then equals a certain amount, the header I have will be changed to the appropriate value.

```
$("#btn-equity").click(function() {
if ( 50 < $('#Equity').val() < 99 ) {
$('#rev1').text("500");
}
});
```

Nothing happens upon clicking the button and I'm unsure as to what the issue is. If anybody could assist, that'd be amazing!

HTML

```
<div class="input-prepend input-append">
            <span class="add-on">$</span>
            <input class="span2" id="Equity" type="text">
            <span class="add-on">.00</span>
        </div>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-success btn-equity" id="btn-equity" value="Determine Equity">
        </center>
        <center>
            <h1 id="rev1">NA</h1>
```

Comment: Is Equity a text field, and rev1 a label?

Comment: Your `if` statement is broken and should always return `true`.  If nothing happens, then your problem is somewhere else.  Can you show us the relevant HTML and any errors from your javascript console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like this...

```
$("#btn-equity").click(function() { 
 var equity = $('#Equity').val()
if (( 50 < equity )&&( equity < 99 )) {
 $('#rev1').html("500");}
 });
```

Comment: Hmm, the value still doesn't change - my HTML looks fine though. (HTML added)

Answer (score 0):

You can't chain comparator operators like that - you need two separate statements:

```
var value = $('#Equity').val();
if ( 50 < value && value < 99 ) {
```

Comment: It's good like this,but in this way if the value is stored only once, and not dynamically, if #Equity is an input number it gives an incorrect result, because it refers always to the old value

Comment: If it is changing mid-comparison, you have other, much more serious problems.

Comment: @SimonVerhoeven Did you try typing `5` into your text field?  It definitely does not work correctly.

Comment: It is doing the first comparison, which will return true or false.  Those get cast to 1 or 0 and then compared to 90, which will always return true.

Comment: My bad, did indeed miss that part. Should indeed be safed to a seperate value then.

Answer (score 0):

it is working to me :
http://jsfiddle.net/3AV7B/

```
$("#btn-equity").click(function() {
  if ( $('#Equity').val() > 50 && $('#Equity').val() < 99 ) {
   $('#rev1').text("500");
  }
});
```